# Как подставить значение в INPUT нажатием на Радио кнопки

Tags: javascript

```
    <label><input type=\"radio\" value=\"Ja\" name=\"vca\" onclick=\"form.name.value=\'Nederlands\';\">Ja</label> 
    <label><input type=\"radio\" value=\"Nee\" name=\"vca\" $vcanee>Nee</label> 
    <label><input type=\"radio\" value=\"Vol\" name=\"vca\" $vcavol>Vol</label>
```

Как подставить значение в поле name, кликнув на одну из радиокнопок?

```
<input type=\"text\" name=\"name\">
<input type=\"text\" name=\"name2\">
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JS:

```js
window.onload = function() {
  var radios = document.getElementsByName('vca');
  
  for (var i = 0; i < radios.length; i++) {
    radios[i].onclick = function() {
      document.getElementsByName('name')[0].value = this.value;
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label><input type="radio" value="Ja" name="vca">Ja</label> 
<label><input type="radio" value="Nee" name="vca" $vcanee>Nee</label> 
<label><input type="radio" value="Vol" name="vca" $vcavol>Vol</label>
<input type="text" name="name">
<input type="text" name="name2">
```

jQuery:

```js
$('input[name="vca"]').click(function(){
  $('input[name="name"]').val($(this).val());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label><input type="radio" value="Ja" name="vca">Ja</label> 
<label><input type="radio" value="Nee" name="vca" $vcanee>Nee</label> 
<label><input type="radio" value="Vol" name="vca" $vcavol>Vol</label>
<input type="text" name="name">
<input type="text" name="name2">
```